# Spring : parameter with (+) is getting ignored by Spring data rest

Tags: java, spring, spring-rest, spring-repositories

I am using Spring in the following code if email address is already Exist then it returns 'true' otherwise `false` , but if email address is like `abc+1@gmail.com` it consider as `abc 1@gmail.com`  (I think) how can I solve this problem ?

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    @Query("select count(u) > 0 from User u where u.email = :email")
    Boolean isEmailExist(@Param("email")String email);
    }
```

Comment: Do you think, or do you know? Add some debugging. See where it fails.